# Exception in checkAndLoadTargetData.Java heap space

Tags: android

I tried increasing the heap size of JVM. But still no luck. I am getting this error when I open the eclipse and when Android SDk is getting loaded. Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to start eclipse with "eclipse [normal arguments] -vmargs -Xmx256M [more VM args]"